# Can't assign "Credit/Contra Revenue Account"

Tags: civicontribute, drupal, 4.7.31

I can't work out how to set up an account to handle credit notes for event cancellations/changes. I've also tried on the demo site without any luck. Can anyone help?
Thanks
Davy

Comment: I've created a bug report for this https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/financial/issues/17